# How can I write an excel formula which looks at data in one range and produces a new cell with its corresponding calls?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

and thanks,

It is hard to describe but easy to understand with an example,

I would like to make Table 2 from the data in Table 1 like in this example

[image: Image of two table in excel]

I have tried a combination of TEXTJOIN and ISNumber searches like this

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ,  ", TRUE, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Australia", A1:A6)), B1:B6, ""))
```

This works to a degree, but I am not sure how to search for the word **Australia** if I do not know the contents of the search range.

I feel there is a way with LET to achieve this but I do not know how.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried up to this point and where are you stuck? Generally, questions that show effort will be rewarded with responses. I'm sure there are many posts that already describe how to accomplish your ask. Please start with those.

Comment: What have you tried so far? One option is UNIQUE for col D and FILTER/TEXTJOIN for col E. Another is GROUPBY with TEXTJOIN. There are others.

Comment: Replace "Australia" with the cell address: `=TEXTJOIN(" ,  ", TRUE, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E2, $A$1:$A$6)), $B$1:$B$6, ""))`

Comment: Change the Australia to the cell? What's the meaning of "don not know the contents of the search range"?